# How to read single line in Unity by using Split("\n")

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, .net-core

.netI am trying to read a .txt file in Unity by using TextMeshProInputField and cannot read single line by using Split("\n")

I am trying to compare a .txt file with a text that I get from an InputField. Yet, by using the following code

`lines = textField.text.Split("\n");`

I cannot read a single line since I do not have any new line string in the input field.

Here is my code for comparing Input Field with the .txt file I have.

`

```
        for (int j = originalData.Count - 1; j > -1; j--)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ReadTXT.readTXT.originalFile.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ReadTXT.readTXT.originalFile[i]==originalData[j])
                {
                    Debug.Log("Original file is" + ReadTXT.readTXT.originalFile[i] + "Removing file is" + originalData[j]);
                }
            }

        }
```

`

Comment: Well look at the value of the text and see what delimits the lines in the text box, note line wraps are not stored as separate lines

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly. you are looking for something like this.

Read the file, split the content by a new line character and then compare each line with textbox text.

```
string str = File.ReadAllText("yourFileName");

var lines = str.Split(Environment.NewLine);
foreach ( var line in lines )
{
    if(textField.text == line)
    {

    }
}
```

you can also use `ReadAllLines` which gives the `string[]` with each line as item

Comment: I also want to get the lines of the textbox text so that I can compare them line by line.

Comment: for that also you can use you can use `Split(Environment.NewLine)`

Comment: I did but it still does not check a single line even if I add a new line into the list. Despite the fact that I make it read, for instance 3 lines, but if it not appeared in the first list, it still shows as it is included in the first list.

Comment: @aesoftware can you give example, your question is not clear

Comment: If your file is large you would rather go for a stream solution to only have one line in memory at a time ;)

Comment: `Split(Environment.NewLine)` is a bit risky if it is not granted that this file was created using the same line break chars

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReadAllLines` to read all lines of the file:

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"file.txt");

 foreach(string line in lines)
 {
    //DoSomething(line);
 }
```

Comment: If your file is large you would rather go for a stream solution to only have one line in memory at a time ;)